# Inserting a vector of unique_ptr into another vector

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have a vector of unique_ptr's and I want to append them to another vector of unique_ptrs.  I would normally do a simple insert:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> bar;
bar.push_back(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo(1)));
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>> baz;
baz.push_back(std::unique_ptr<foo>(new foo(2)));
bar.insert(bar.end(), baz.begin(), baz.end());
```

However this gives me compile errors similar to this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:335: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = foo; _Dp = std::default_delete<foo>]'
    *__result = *__first;
              ^
```

Is there a convenient way to insert or do I have to iterate over baz and push_back on bar?  I'm currently using gcc 4.8.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is not assignable with normal assignment operator (the error says it's deleted). You can only *move* them:

```
bar.insert(bar.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(baz.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(baz.end())
);
```

Of course, this transfers the ownership of the managed object and original pointers will have `nullptr` value.

Comment: That's probably a better answer than mine, since it allows the vector to reserve enough space before moving.

Comment: Thanks!  The make_move_iterator is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually `unique_ptr` is one of the few types that has a specified moved-from state:  `nullptr`.  Otherwise the contract of unique ownership could not be held.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Yes, that was poorly worded. Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You can't copy them; you'll have to move them.

```
std::move(baz.begin(), baz.end(), std::back_inserter(bar));
```