# How to insert several unique_ptrs into vector at once

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>
```

and would like to insert several new `unique_ptr<int>`'s into it at a specified location.  There is the member function `std::vector::insert(iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val)` but alas, the restrictions on copying `unique_ptr`'s does not allow the use of this overload.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487714/inserting-a-vector-of-unique-ptr-into-another-vector), however that is for inserting `unique_ptr`'s that already exist in another vector.  I want to create new ones.

I realize I can do it with a loop, for example to insert 3 new items to the beginning of the vector:

```
for (int n = 0; n != 3; ++n)
   vec.insert(vec.begin(), std::make_unique<int>(0));
```

However I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this, and possibly one that allocates the new memory up-front.

Edit for clarification: the number of items to add to the vector is completely arbitrary - I wrote 3 in my example code but it could be any value and not necessarily one that's known at compile time.

Comment: Since you need to allocate a separate `int` for each `std::unique_ptr`, there is no cleaner way to do this without using a loop that calls `std::make_unique()`, or moving from another array/container of pointers.  Otherwise, re-think your design.  For example, maybe have a single `std::vector<int>` with 3 elements. Or a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` holding a 3-element array, and then a separate `std::vector<int*>` containing raw pointers into that array.

Comment: ...or  `std::generate_n(
       std::inserter(vec, vec.begin()),
       3,
       std::bind(std::make_unique<int,int&>,0)
    );` But I wouldn't call that clean.

Answer (score 2):

There is two different kinds of memory being allocated here. There is the memory allocated in the `vector` for the `unique_ptr` itself (which will not be very much, just a pointer per unique_ptr). And then the dynamically allocated memory for the object managed by each `unique_ptr`.

You cannot allocate *all* the memory up-front as the dynamically allocated memory for the object within each `unique_ptr` must be allocated separately.

But if you want to avoid reallocations of the memory for the vector due to multiple `insert` calls you could do a reserve first:

```
vec.reserve(vec.size() + n);
```

I doubt it will have any impact for `n` as small as 3 though.

More of an issue is that for each `insert` the vector has to move all the contents of the `vector` after the insert point along by one. Moving `unique_ptr` is cheap but it could add-up.

It is certainly not cleaner, but you could do the moving yourself once using `std::move_backward`. Resize the vector to the size required, move all the elements along and then move-assign the `unique_ptr` in the elements where you want to insert:

```
auto prev_size = vec.size();
vec.resize(prev_size + 3);
auto prev_end = vec.begin() + prev_size;
std::move_backward(vec.begin(), prev_end, vec.end());
for (int n = 0; n != 3; ++n)
  vec[n] = std::make_unique<int>(0);
```

Another, perhaps cleaner, way of achieving the same thing is to create your own custom forward-iterator to use in the `std::vector::insert(const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);` overload of `insert`:

```
template<typename T>
struct UniquePtrInserter : std::iterator< 
                           std::forward_iterator_tag,
                           std::unique_ptr<T>,
                           std::ptrdiff_t,  
                           const std::unique_ptr<T>*,
                           std::unique_ptr<T>>{
  int n_;
public:
  explicit UniquePtrInserter<T>(int n = 0) : n_(n) {}
  UniquePtrInserter<T>& operator++() {n_++; return *this;}
  bool operator==(UniquePtrInserter<T> other) const {return n_ == other.n_;}
  bool operator!=(UniquePtrInserter<T> other) const {return !(*this == other);}
  std::unique_ptr<T> operator*() const {return std::make_unique<T>(); }
};

vec.insert(vec.begin(), UniquePtrInserter<int>(0), UniquePtrInserter<int>(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know at compile-time how many pointers you want to put in the vector, you can use a function like the following one:

```
#include<vector>
#include<memory>
#include<cstddef>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto gen(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
    int arr[] = { (vec.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(0)), I)... };
    (void)arr;
    return vec;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto create() {
    return gen(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main() {
    auto vec = create<3>();
}
```

Comment: alternate, avoiding arr alltogether: `(vec.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(0 * I)), ... );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_n` to avoid the  raw loop

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;
generate_n( back_inserter(vec), 3, []() { return make_unique<int>(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to use a *move iterator* to move the elements, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>

using T = std::unique_ptr<int>;

void print_vec(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& x: vec) {
         std::cout << ' ' << *x;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename V, typename ...X>
void emplace(V& v, typename V::const_iterator i, X&&... x) {
    T a[] = { std::forward<X>(x)... };
    v.insert(i, std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(a)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(a)));
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
    emplace(vec, vec.begin(), std::make_unique<int>(601), std::make_unique<int>(602), std::make_unique<int>(603));
    print_vec(vec);    
    emplace(vec, std::next(vec.begin()), std::make_unique<int>(501), std::make_unique<int>(502), std::make_unique<int>(503));
    print_vec(vec);

}
```

I've provided a simple wrapper function which takes a sequence (as variadic argument sequence) and inserts this into the vector using a `move_iterator`.

But you can use the `move_iterator` to move from any container that will support the move operator.