# Error when using std::make_move_iterator to insert a std::list<std::unique_ptr>> into another one

Tags: c++11, linked-list, insert, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I've been reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487804/1485885) about moving elements from a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` to another one using `std::make_move_iterator`. It works flawlessly:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c1;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> c2;
c1.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
c2.insert(c2.end(), std::make_move_iterator(c1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(c1.end()));
```

Now I tried to change it to use a different container (`std::list`):

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> c1;
std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> c2;
c1.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
c2.insert(c2.end(), std::make_move_iterator(c1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(c1.end()));
```

But compilation fails with:

> error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'

However, it does work if lists contain other objects (like `std::string`):

```
std::list<std::string> s1;
std::list<std::string> s2;
s2.insert(s2.end(), std::make_move_iterator(s1.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(s1.end()));
```

Now, if I use [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487828/1485885) from the same question, which uses `std::back_inserter` and `std::move`, it works with both `std::vector` and `std::list`:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> c1;
std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> c2;
c1.push_back(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int));
std::move(c1.begin(), c1.end(), std::back_inserter(c2));
```

As far as I understand, this solution basically moves each item individually when back inserting on the second container.

My question is, why using `std::make_move_iterator` on a `std::list` of `std::unique_ptr` doesn't work but it does with `std::vector` or if the list element is of a different type?

*Note:* I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: VS2010 is ancient. [Works for me](http://rextester.com/AYXH86359) with VS2017.

Comment: Interesting... thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it would have any workaround? I have another solution as noted in the question, but I won't be able to migrate from VS 2010 for a while

Comment: For moving between lists, you probably should be using `splice`.

Comment: Nice recommendation, thanks! As you say, it is actually both more direct and self-documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is that Visual Studio 2010's implementation of `std::list::insert` doesn't support moving semantics. Internally, the `std::list::insert` invokes a method called `_Insert`, which is declared as follows in VS 2010:

```
void _Insert(const_iterator _Where, const _Ty& _Val)
```

In VS 2017 (not checked for other versions), it calls the same method but it is declared as:

```
void _Insert(_Unchecked_const_iterator _Where, _Valty&&... _Val)
```

As seen, VS 2017 uses an rvalue reference, therefore calling the moving constructor of `std::unique_ptr` when making the insertion. On the other hand, VS 2010 uses an lvalue reference instead, so at some moment the copy constructor is called, which is declared private for `std::unique_ptr`, generating the compilation error.

---

**Conclusion**

In VS 2010 there is no way to use the solution based on `std::make_move_iterator` because how `std::list::insert` is implemented. Options for appending a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>` into another one include:

- Using the [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

  ```
  std::move(c1.begin(), c1.end(), std::back_inserter(c2));
  ```
- Using [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) (credit to [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391739/error-when-using-stdmake-move-iterator-to-insert-a-stdliststdunique-ptr#comment75791924_44391739)), which is very useful since it can be directly used with lists returned by functions:

  ```
  c2.splice(c2.end(), c1);
  ```