# Append vector of unique ptr to another via member function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I want to move a vector of unique ptrs to a vector of unique ptrs I have stored in a class. I have reduced this to a minimum example here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;  
};


class B
{

public:

    void AddAs(const vector<unique_ptr<A>>& vv)
    {

        vec.insert(vec.end(),
            std::make_move_iterator(vv.begin()),
            std::make_move_iterator(vv.end())
        );
    }

    vector<unique_ptr<A>> vec;
};


int main() {    
    vector<unique_ptr<A>> v;
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(make_unique<A>());
    }
    B b;
    b.AddAs(v);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/76iNIM

This trying to follow the answer from [Inserting a vector of unique_ptr into another vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487714/inserting-a-vector-of-unique-ptr-into-another-vector)

But this doesn't compile as it says that is using the copy operator.

I am sure this is a stupid question, but I am new to C++ and I am struggling to see where the copy is.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move from a vector, that you passed by const reference, as moving requires modification. So change that method to:

```
void AddAs(vector<unique_ptr<A>>&& vv)
```

Passing by value will also work:

```
void AddAs(vector<unique_ptr<A>> vv)
```

Note you need to change calling code:

```
b.AddAs(std::move(v));
```

which is actually good as shows the reader that vector would be moved from.

[live example](https://ideone.com/tAQqdn)

Comment: @NicolBolas why did you remove lvalue reference? It is not really readable, but still would work.

Comment: Of course it will work. But it's a bad idea to give people bad ideas. And moving from an lvalue reference is pretty much *always wrong*. It means that, at the site where the function is called, there is no indication that the object will be moved from. And since moving from an object leaves it in an undefined state, that means using it later is dubious. Preventing that is a big part of why `std::move` and rvalue references *exist*. The other reason being of course that you can't pass prvalues to lvalue reference parameters.

Comment: "It means that, at the site where the function is called, there is no indication that the object will be moved from." yes, but unfortunately that is the case for almost any call where lvalue reference passed - method suppose to change it but there is no indication on calling site. But I am not sure this is good enough reason to prohibit passing by lvalue reference in general.

Comment: There's a difference between whether or not the function will change it and whether or not the function will move from it. Despite the latter being a subset of the former, the latter is a much more damaging process. Generally speaking, it is incredibly rude to completely destroy the contents of a non-`const` lvalue reference parameter. And destroying the contents of an object is *exactly* what move does.